# Why does a retrieve request end up calling `get_queryset( )`?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-rest-viewsets

The DRF helps you make a simple API that exposes an endpoint for listings of an object and the details for a specific object.

My viewset looks like this:

```
class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
  serializer_class = someSerializer
  queryset = User.objects.all()
  
  def get_queryset(self):
    if self.request.user.has_perm('some.custom_permission'):
      return (
        super()
         .get_queryset()
         .filter(<some_custom_filtering>)
      )
    return super().get_queryset().filter(id=self.request.user.id)
```

Say my API is accessible from '<some_domain>/api/' (after registering my router appropriately). To get a listing of all my users I will call
`<some_domain>/api/users/`
And for a specific user (Michael Jordan)
`<some_domain>/api/users/23`

Both endpoints work as expected.

Just wondering why the call to retrieve a particular user still ends up going through the get_queryset() function.

Internally, the `ModelViewSet` class inherits functionality from the `mixins.RetrieveModelMixin` and the `mixins.ListModelMixin`. And if one goes even deeper, at least in `djangorestframework==3.12.4`, the `RetrieveModelMixin` gets a specific object, serializes it and returns the serialized data. While the `ListModelMixin`, calls the `get_queryset()` function.

I know that overriding the get_object() function in my `UserViewSet` view will make sure my retrieve object calls end up there (calling `get_object` instead of `get_queryset()`, but in its absence I don't get how or why the `get_queryset()` function is involved.

Comment: `get_object` actually calls `get_queryset`. Have a look [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/71e6c30034a1dd35a39ca74f86c371713e762c79/rest_framework/generics.py#L75) for the `get_object` implementation.

Comment: Thanks ⭐️. I just didn't dig deep enough 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queryset is the way to bind view to a specific model.
You can create entire api with retrieve, list, update, create and delete actions simply by extending a few mixins and specifying queryset and serializer class, without actual method implementation.

Whatever you do, it eventualy ends up as `ModelClass.objects.some_method`.
As @Brian said, `get_object` also uses `get_queryset`, and also `filter_queryset` so retrieve/delete will raise 404 if you use filter and object does not pass it even if it actually exists.